# Read Lotus Notes documents and items from NSF file with C#

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-notes

How can I get all Lotus Notes documents (e.g. mails and their content) from a **Lotus Notes** inbox from an **NSF** Files with C# and the usage of **interop.domino.dll**?

I want to use the following snippet:

```
Domino.NotesSession m_session = null;

...

this.m_session = new Domino.NotesSession();
this.m_session.Initialize("");

Domino.NotesDatabase db = null;
this.m_session.GetDatabase("", "C:\test.nsf", false);

Domino.NotesDocumentCollection col = db.AllDocuments;

for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; ++i)
{
         Domino.NotesDocument doc = col.GetNthDocument(i);

         ...
}
```

How can I access the items of each document? For example I want subject, who, date, time,...

How can I iterate throug all items of a document?

How can I extract attachments?

Is the NotesSQL ODBC driver a good alternative to the COM API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work.  The GetItemValue method in Lotusscript returns a value array, but usually you're just going to need the value at the first index.  I'm not sure if it works the same way with COM, but the debugger can help you figure that out.

Also if you're processing a lot of documents it is much faster to iterate using the GetFirstDocument/GetNextDocument methods than it is to use the GetNthDocument method.

```
Domino.NotesDocument doc = col.GetFirstDocument(doc);
while (doc != null) {

     string subject = doc.GetItemValue("subject")[0];
     string who = doc.GetItemValue("sendto")[0];

     Domino.NotesDocument doc = col.GetNextDocument(doc);
}
```